# How to set ActiveMQ message header in Mule?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, mule

I'm using MuleStudio 3.5.0 and trying to create a flow which sends a message to an ActiveMQ queue. That queue is consumed by an old existing service (written in .Net) which I want to integrate in my workflow. That service expects that the message's **header** `Type` is set to "*DoStuff*". How can I achieve this?

I tried the following flow. Note that for testing purposes I set the payload of the ActiveMQ message by hand via the `DoStuff` class, the HTTP connector is just for triggering the workflow:

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="DoStuffBean" name="DoStuffBean" class="foo.DoStuff"/>
</spring:beans>
<flow name="Flow1" doc:name="Flow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8199" path="activemq" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <component doc:name="Java" class="com.kws.mule.DoStuff"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="MyServiceQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:object-to-jmsmessage-transformer name="ObjectToJmsMessage" />
        <message-properties-transformer>
            <add-message-property key="Type" value="DoStuff" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

But this does not work, because not the **header** `Type` is set, but a property. This is shown in the image from the *ActiveMQ broker manager console*:

[image: The property Type is set, but not the header]

For reference here is the `DoStuff` class:

```
public class DoStuff implements Callable {
    private String jobId;
    private String createdTime;

    public String getJobId()
    {
        return this.jobId;
    }

    public String getResult()
    {
        return this.createdTime;
    }

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        DoStuff result = new DoStuff();
        result.jobId = "abd4df7b-0f31-41b4-826a-3dbbe77df7eb";
        result.createdTime = "0001-01-01T00:00:00";

        eventContext.getMessage().setPayload(result);
        return eventContext.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This flow should work:

```
<flow name="Flow1" doc:name="Flow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8199" path="activemq" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <component doc:name="Java" class="com.kws.mule.DoStuff"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="MyServiceQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:object-to-jmsmessage-transformer name="ObjectToJmsMessage" />
        <expression-transformer returnSourceIfNull="true"
            doc:name="Expression"
            expression="#[payload.setJMSType(&quot;DoStuff&quot;); return payload]" />
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

in `MEL`, you could do

```
<set-property propertyName="Type" value="Set your value here"/>
```

This will set an **outbound property** on the `Mule Message` which would be received by `JMS Queue` as inbound property

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this sets the _property_ `Type` of the message, but not the _header_ which is what I want. I guess my answer was not clear enough, so I updated it a bit.

Comment: What do you get when you try to retrieve this property. Try creating another flow with `inbound-endpoint` as this active MQ and retrieve this property there. See which one you get

Comment: You are right, I get the property if I build a new consuming `inbound-endpoint` with Mule. But the already existing service which consumes the ActiveMQ queue was not built with Mule but is an old .Net application which expects the Type _header_ is filled. Unfortunately I have no access to the ActiveMQ consuming sourcecode since this part is proprietary, hence I would like to set the header of the JMS message.

Comment: `<set-property>` is the best way to set header. You should try to see what _Type_ is .Net application getting. May be its getting the right type.

Comment: It cannot parse the message since the .Net application has no clue that such a custom property exists, it still needs the header :( If I send a custom message via the _ActiveMQ broker manager console_ and set the Type header, the .Net application works instead.